# Rule of zero - default constructor not generated

Tags: c++, default-constructor, rule-of-zero

I was reading this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

And my understanding from this is that, if you want to have a base class with a virtual destructor, the you need to define all 5 special functions (extracted from the rule of 0 section):

```cpp
class base_of_five_defaults
{
 public:
    base_of_five_defaults(const base_of_five_defaults&) = default;
    base_of_five_defaults(base_of_five_defaults&&) = default;
    base_of_five_defaults& operator=(const base_of_five_defaults&) = default;
    base_of_five_defaults& operator=(base_of_five_defaults&&) = default;
    virtual ~base_of_five_defaults() = default;
};
```

however when I try to instaiate that class I get the error saying that "default c'tor is not created":

```cpp
    base_of_five_defaults b; // Error
```

Then if I generate the default its ok:

```cpp
base_of_five_defaults() = default;
```

But I did not understand that this was needed at all... so I am confused why its not there. I *thought* the only reason the compiler does not generate a default constructor is if you specify a non-default constructor...

If you DO need to specify the default c'tor then the class in the example is un-constructable - which seems odd.

Here is the link to my full live example: https://godbolt.org/z/qPvjd6r51

---

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor:

> Implicitly-declared default constructor
>
> If no user-declared
> constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (struct, class,
> or union), the compiler will always declare a default constructor as
> an inline public member of its class.

I guess this means if `base_of_five_defaults(const base_of_five_defaults&) = default;` is declared then it is considered user-declared even though its "default"?

Comment: its meant to be used as base class (though that does not change the fact that it is not possible to construct it)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 but a base class *can* be constructable unless its specifically abstracted... but I see your point - I do find the example a bit odd though :)

Comment: the example is in contrast to "C.21: If you define or =delete any copy, move, or destructor function, define or =delete them all" Either I am missing something, or they just missed to include it in the example. Actually I am not sure how to take `base_of_five_defaults`, is it meant as a real utlity or merely to demonstrate the point? I am leaning towards the latter

Comment: Because you defined at least one explicit ctor, thus implicit default ctor is removed?

Comment: oh wait a sec. I misread C21. It actually does not mention constructors. There must be something I am missing ;)

Comment: After edit: yes, implicit ctor is not the same as explicitly defined ctor associated to the default implementation.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959659/c-rule-of-zero-what-is-user-declared-constructor

Comment: I updated my question - which I think boils down to is `base_of_five_defaults(const base_of_five_defaults&) = default;` user defined? - I guess that it is

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - ah, I think the answer in there says that *any* c'tor written by the user is user-declared (sounds a bit obvious when put that way)... so the example is just a bit of a "mis-lead" from my point of view :)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thanks - I think that was the bit of info I was missing

Comment: please add as a answers - or perhaps we can close this question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess this means if `base_of_five_defaults(const base_of_five_defaults&) = default;` is declared then it is considered user-declared even though its "default"?

**Yes**. `base_of_five_defaults(base_of_five_defaults&&) = default;` declares **a**<sup>1</sup> *defaulted* *user-declared* constructor.

The `= default` makes the compiler generate the definition of such a constructor, but it has been declared by the user.

The C++ standard does not provide an explicit definition of *user-declared* so English kicks in for it to mean, well, "declared by the user".

This is where `[class.default.ctor]/1` bites you:

> #### [`[class.default.ctor]/1`](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#class.default.ctor-1.sentence-2)
>
> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X for which each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a default argument (including the case of a constructor with no parameters).
> **If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted ([dcl.fct.def]).**
> An implicitly-declared default constructor is an inline public member of its class.

---

<sup>1)</sup> It doesn't matter if it is a constructor with or without parameters, see wording of `[class.default.ctor]/1`.