# Is the term user-declared constructor ambiguous or is it self explanatory

Tags: c++, constructor

I came to [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624520/whats-the-definition-of-user-declared-constructor-in-the-c-standard) that the C++ standard doesn't define the term `user-declared constructor` but it uses that term at many places. Now to my current understanding, the term `user-declared constructor` is self explanatory.

But one user disagrees with my above understanding as they [say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624520/whats-the-definition-of-user-declared-constructor-in-the-c-standard#comment130012905_73624520):

> It's not entirely self explanatory. The place things get tricky is with special member functions of things in the standard library. Even though a normal user never writes the code for constructors of things like std::string, I believe those still fall within the realm of "user declared" special member functions--but I can't quote anything from the standard to back that up, and there are fair arguments to be made that they're not.

---

So **my question is** that should the term `user-declared constructors` be defined by the standard? That is, is there any example where there is some ambiguity due to the term as said by the above quoted comment or is the term self-explanatory.

My current understanding is that `user-declared` in this context means  "written by the user". That is, "which is not implicitly synthesized".

Comment: "user declared" doesn't mean that I personally have to declare it, someone else could have. Like a library author, including for the standard library.

Comment: @BoP Yes ofcourse I know that. I never  said that " I personally have to declare it". Instead I mean that it is "written by the user whoever that user may be" and as long as it is not implicitly synthesized by the compiler.

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based.  Perhaps this is something that should be improved in the standard, but IMO the standard mailing list is a better place to have such discussions rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: @Kal - So where is the confusion? If the standard were to define "user-declared constructors" as "constructors declared by the user", would that improve anything? Is there a better definition?

Comment: @BoP I think the OP asked the question because the user [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624520/whats-the-definition-of-user-declared-constructor-in-the-c-standard#comment130012905_73624520) was claiming that the term is not self explanatory. Note also that i do think that the term is self explanatory as also said in my previous [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624520/whats-the-definition-of-user-declared-constructor-in-the-c-standard#comment130012882_73624520) in the same thread.

Comment: @BoP Also the same user [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624520/whats-the-definition-of-user-declared-constructor-in-the-c-standard#comment130013030_73624520): *"In fact, I've talked with a committee member about this who agreed it was ambiguous and should be defined (but was busy with enough other things he wasn't willing to delay them to work on this)"*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Rule of Zero & what is "user-declared" constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959659/c-rule-of-zero-what-is-user-declared-constructor)

Comment: Yes, "user-declared" is the opposite of "implicitly declared"; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959659/c-rule-of-zero-what-is-user-declared-constructor . The rest of this question seems off-topic for SO. (But IMHO it might be reasonable to open a CWG issue and request adding a definition for "user-declared function" in the Terms and Definitions section, alongside ["program-defined type"](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.prog.def.type).)

Answer (score 1):

This is [CWG2632](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2632.html) and the potential ambiguity(if any) will be resolved by adding the resolution given there:

> **user-declared [defns.user.declared]**
>
> declared in a translation unit using a `declarator-id`
>
> [ Note 1 to entry: In contrast, some special member functions can be implicitly declared by the implementation. -- end note]